# How to broadcast raw transaction using bitcoin-ruby?

Tags: ruby, transactions, broadcast, bitcoin, bitcoin-testnet

How to broadcast raw transaction using bitcoin-ruby?
I used bitcoin-ruby gem from https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby

```
    Bitcoin.network = :testnet

    address="muLGqMS6tkqb9sBQ4sqeXjMzaV8rk8o3gv"

    url = "https://testnet.blockexplorer.com/api/addr/#{address}"
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    if Connect.valid_json(response)
      response = JSON.parse(response)
      $transactions = response["transactions"]
    end

    prev_hash = $transactions[0]

    url = "https://testnet.blockexplorer.com/api/rawtx/#{prev_hash}"
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    if Connect.valid_json(response)
      response = JSON.parse(response)
      response = response['rawtx'].to_s
      $prev_tx = Bitcoin::P::Tx.new(response.htb)
    end

    prev_tx = $prev_tx
    prev_tx_output_index = 0
    value = 50000 #0.0005 btc

    tx = Bitcoin::Protocol::Tx.new
    tx.add_in Bitcoin::Protocol::TxIn.new(prev_tx.binary_hash, prev_tx_output_index, 0)

    tx.add_out Bitcoin::Protocol::TxOut.value_to_address(value, "msPHTrHSktDLMwPXcMYwWTqth3ZyykN17H") # <- dest address (our donation address)

    # if all in and outputs are defined, start signing inputs.
    key = Bitcoin.open_key(Connect.get_private_key) # <- privkey
    sig = Bitcoin.sign_data(key, tx.signature_hash_for_input(0, prev_tx))
    tx.in[0].script_sig = Bitcoin::Script.to_signature_pubkey_script(sig, [key.public_key_hex].pack("H*"))
    #tx.in[0].add_signature_pubkey_script(sig, key.public_key_hex)

    # finish check
    tx = Bitcoin::Protocol::Tx.new( tx.to_payload )
    p tx.verify_input_signature(0, prev_tx) == true
    hex =  tx.to_payload.unpack("H*")[0] # hex binary
    puts hex.to_s
#Error sending transaction: Transaction 4a762238529450737b85ad481deae0e836e623afd63e04a29a5b90363c0345fd has too high fees: 12372992.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to remove your rant. Question length restrictions are in place to encourage new users to provide enough information to make the question specific. Right now, I still do not 100% know what you are struggling with. Please add to your question what you are trying to achieve, what your code does and (if applicable) any error messages. This makes it a lot easier to answer your question.

Comment: @m00am I am using bitcoin-ruby gem to make transaction. So, transaction created successfully, but during pushing it to network, I had an error : #Error sending transaction: Transaction 4a762238529450737b85ad481deae0e836e623afd63e04a29a5b90363c0345fd has too high fees: 12372992.

Comment: @AyanNurbolat generally the transaction fee should be less that 0.1 BTC, and you are sending "value = 50000 #0.0005 btc" the remaining bitcoins are treated as transaction fee. So increase the amount value of transaction and try it.

Answer (score -1):

The fee of a transaction is just the difference between the input and the output value. In you case, your output value is 0.0005 BTC. If you choose an input which is larger than the output you want to send as well as the fee, you have to create a change output to send the rest back to your wallet as well, otherwise it will all go to the miners as fees. For example, if your input was 0.25 BTC, and you wanted to send 0.15 BTC and only pay 0.01 BTC fee, your transaction would need to have two outputs, one for 0.15 BTC, and one for 0.09 BTC back to an address you own, so that the total fee is just (0.25-(0.15+0.9) = 0.01)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [sibit](https://github.com/yegor256/sibit), my Ruby gem:

```
require 'sibit'
sibit = Sibit.new
pkey = sibit.generate
address = sibit.create(pkey)
balance = sibit.balance(address)
target = sibit.create(pkey) # where to send coins to
change = sibit.create(pkey) # where the change will sent to
tx = sibit.pay(pkey, 10_000_000, 'XL', [address], target, change)
```